# Why not say ‘in a pencil’, but say ‘in pencil’?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, indefinite-article

We say:

> Shall I write in ink or in pencil.

Why not say:

> Shall I write in ink or in **a** pencil?

Comment: This thread might be useful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168263/is-there-any-difference-in-meaning-if-at-all-between-to-write-in-pen-and-to-w

Answer (score 5):

In this context, 'pencil', like 'ink', is a material. You can use *in* with materials, but it wouldn't make sense for something to be *in a pencil*. 'A pencil' refers to the tool, and so one uses 'with' i.e. *with a pencil*.

If an English person said *write in a pencil*, I would understand 'a pencil' to mean "a particular type or colour of the *material* 'pencil'". In the same way, one can 'write in an ink', but this sounds more normal than 'in a pencil'.

Answer (score 0):

Graphite is the material used in pencils, but is never used when referring to a writing format. Instead, we use "pencil". You would use "in a pencil" as follows: "What qualities are you looking for *in a pencil*? I want it to be medium hardness with an eraser."